# ビューポートの使い方とポリライン設定との違いについて

Tags: ijcad

レイアウト画面にてビューポートの使い方及び
既存のレイアウト図において、ビューポートの囲いが、ポリライン設定になっております。
詳しく状況を指南頂きたく、おもいました。
宜しくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　こちらのご質問ですが、最終的に解決したい問題はなんでしょうか？　どのような回答が来ることが望ましいでしょうか。たとえば、「ポリライン設定になっている」ということは書かれていますが、そこからどうしたいのかが書かれていませんでした。質問文を [edit] して、何を質問したいのかを分かりやすくしていただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: こちらはAPIに関連した質問でしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

> 既存のレイアウト図において、ビューポートの囲いが、ポリライン設定になっております。

ビューポートがポリラインでクリップされているのではないかと思います。（VPCLIPコマンド）
以下の方法でポリライン設定を解除することができます。

1. VPCLIPコマンドを実行する
2. 囲いがポリライン設定になっているビューポートを選択する
3. [削除(D)]オプションを選択する

Comment: ありがとうございます。